# ActiveReports Change Image size at runtime

Tags: activereports

I have an image that is 300px width and has to be set at runtime.  At design time, the image is a different size and depending on a flag, the image has to be changed.  How do I set the image width in C#/VB.NET.

I cast the object as a Picture.  The Width property only takes a SINGLE value and presume its inches.  How do I tell the picture control that I'm passing in is the pixel size not inches?

Comment: It is not possible, You have to convert the Pixel to inches to set the width of the Picture Control.

Comment: Is there a built in helper function that will do the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can set the size in pixels, convert it to inches (as the GrapeCity Team suggests), and apply it to your picture based on a conditional variable:

The following code is added in the Script section of your report:

```
Sub Detail_Format

    Dim intSizeInPixels As Integer = 300

    Dim dblSizeInInches as Double = intSizeInPixels / 96

    Dim mfFlag As Boolean = True

    If mfFlag Then
        Picture1.Width = dblSizeInInches
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: Actual Code]

[image: Before Resizing]

[image: After Resizing]